# What is the name of this feature in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Let say, we have a variable:

```
const name = 'bob';
```

I want to define an object with key-value pair that holds `name` as key and `'bob'` as value. Then, I do this:

```
const obj = { name };
```

JavaScript automatically infers the key-value pair from the variable defined. How does JS do it and what is the name of this feature?

Comment: Shorthand property names.

Comment: The above comment is correct, read more here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#New_notations_in_ECMAScript_2015

Comment: How could we call this way of initialize an object? Is it a feature, a sugar syntax maybe, a notation, or something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are called [shorthand property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#New_notations_in_ECMAScript_2015)